# Is it possible to get phonetic text offline

Tags: ios

I need to show a phonetic text when a text is entered. for eg.

```
hello = /həˈləʊ,hɛ-/
```

as per [Google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hello%20meaning)

if **hello** is given I want **/həˈləʊ,hɛ-/** this text as output. Or the data source of below page

[image]

We have `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` class but `+ (BOOL)dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:(NSString *)term;` method only returns BOOL. like wise I want something which return me the phonetic text or the datasource.   Please help

Comment: dear down voter please answer the question

Comment: The doc says for `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` that `It should not be used to display wordlists, create a standalone dictionary app, or republish the content in any form.`

Comment: I m not making the dictionary app.. this the app design  http://uimovement.com/ui/133/phonetic-transcription/

Comment: I understand what you want, but I said that you can't use `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` for it.

Comment: i jus was gone through it.. not that with which i need to achieve

Comment: You want the phonetic of a term, right? You attempted with `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`, right? It is not possible. If this is not what you want to ask, reformulate your question; at least...